# How to adapt this script to include a checkbox check if checked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I use this script between my `head` tags that will force the user to scroll through a `textarea` before hitting submit button

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

function textareaAtEnd(textareaObj)
{
    return ((textareaObj.scrollTop + textareaObj.offsetHeight) > textareaObj.scrollHeight);
}

function formValidation(formObj)
{
    if (textareaAtEnd(formObj.licenseAgreement))
    {
        return true;

    } else {
        alert ("Please scroll to the end to move on.")
        return false;
    }

}

// -->
</script>
```

My `<form>` looks like this:

```
<form action="step2.php" method="post" onSubmit="return formValidation(this);">
    <textarea name="licenseAgreement" rows="20" cols="90">Very long license agreement text</textarea>
    <br />
    <input name="agree" type="checkbox" value="yes" /> I have read and agreed the above license agreement
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="CONTINUE">
</form>
```

How can I adapt this JavaScript to also check if `<input name="agree" type="checkbox" value="yes" />` is checked and if not to echo a message to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do

```
function formValidation(formObj) {
    if(!formObj.agree.checked) {
        alert ("Please agree to terms.")
        return false;
    } else if (textareaAtEnd(formObj.licenseAgreement)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert ("Please scroll to the end to move on.")
        return false;
    }

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qc3UN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
if (document.getElementById('agree').checked == false) { 
    alert('Check the agree box dummy!');
}
```

Using ID's is a best practice I would always recommend using for client-side code.

So you would change your validation function to:

```
function formValidation() {
    if (textareaAtEnd(document.getElementById('licenseAgreement')) == false) {
        alert ("Please scroll to the end to move on.")
        return false;
    } 
    else if (document.getElementById('agree').checked == false) {
        alert('Check the agree box dummy!');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also be sure to add an `id="agree"` to your `<input type="checkbox"` and `id="licenseAgreement"` to your textarea...

So it should look like this:

```
<input name="agree" id="agree" type="checkbox" value="yes" />

...

<textarea name="licenseAgreement" id="licenseAgreement" rows="20" cols="90">
```

And your form tag, you can remove the `this` parameter:

```
onSubmit="return formValidation();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `checked` property :

```
var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("agree")[0];

if(checkbox.checked) 
  alert("Check that");
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a collection.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
<input name="agree" type="checkbox" value="yes" />
```

**With**

```
<input name="agree" id="agree" type="checkbox" value="yes" />
```

Add `id=agree` attribute for checkbox.

```
if(document.getElementById("agree").checked == false)
{
    alert("Checkbox is not checked , please select checkbox");
}
```